# Trying to reference data in variable rows after matching specific cell in excel

Tags: excel, dynamic, excel-formula, reference, row

[image: Actual redacted data example]

In Excel I'm trying to paste in weekly time card reports and then reference the bottom line of each section which contains the yellow highlighted text string in column B (report contains 15-20 sections with variable row differences).

Without using VBA, is there a way to identify an employee ID (Column A), then calculate how many rows below that ID that the last text string cell is located in column B (Highlighted in yellow in the example). Then use that row difference to offset the INDEX formula to grab correct row from the table.

I was using INDEX/MATCH to find the employee ID and then trying to offset the row return per employee manually when I realized that the different job codes rendered that formula inaccurate.

I had used this to reference the proper columns with the offset for one of the weeks, but each week varies. The "+17" at the end of the below formula is where I need the variable row difference to grab the yellow highlighted cell.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$100,(MATCH(A61,$B1:$B$100,0)+17))
```

Thanks in advance, hopefully I provided the right info to answer the question if there is a solution!

Comment: are the words "LAST ROW" really there?  or does it say "subtotal" or "total"? if its actually blank, is there any data in the remainder of the column below?  Is there an anticipated maximum number of row entries, ie there will never be more than 50 or 100 or 1000 rows?  Also is the employee ID a number or a number stored as a string?

Comment: Sorry I should have used the actual table (was concerned about sensitive data but have redacted that). I just changed the image to reflect that. I need the Yellow Highlighted cell which is a whole text string since our CPA's program outputs a combined text string rather than separate cells.

Comment: Is the employee ID # actually part of the first column?  it looks like its part of a joined cells, and second, if that ID number is in cell A2, does the following formula return TRUE?  `=isnumber(A2)`

Comment: is that string constently 8 rows below Totals?

Comment: conversley does that string always start with ERFUTA? or perhaps that yellow cell is the only cell in the column is the a : in it?

Comment: Also what column is that string in? as it looks to be between the pay description column and the rate column

Comment: After reviewing a number of sections, it appears that yes the Yellow line is always 8 rows below the Total. Also Emp ID and the Taxes (ERFUTA) are merged cells. I can retrieve the data by referencing A for the ID and B for the Taxes. The text string does always start with ERFUTA and starts in column B.

Comment: So if I got this straight, your index formula above is supposed to return the yellow text corresponding to an employee ID given in A61?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a revamp of the thought process, the following formula will return the information corresponding to as specific employee and their tax information which is stored in column B in a cell with "EFURTA" in it.  No other cell in B within the employee block can contain "EFURTA".  If that happens only the first occurence will be returned.

Assuming your data is layed out per the image below, the following formula will return the information you are looking for:

```
=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$80)/((FIND("ERFUTA",$B$1:$B$80)>0)*(ROW($A$1:$A$80)>MATCH(D2,$A$1:$A$80,0))),1))
```

Adjust the ranges to suit your data.

[image: POC]

If you just want the row number, just grab the aggregate part of the formula and drop the index.

Comment: I tried using this formula however I believe I presented the information incorrectly by trying to simplify the example. I have updated the picture to show that I am needed a text string located at the bottom of each section (highlighted in yellow). I used the forumla you proposed which gave me a sum of the hours in between. I however need the number of rows between the Emp ID and the Yellow row so that i can index reference the exact cell location of that yellow text string. Thanks for you help! =)

Comment: This worked wonderfully! thank you so much for taking the time to help. much appreciated! These reports end up being 300-400 rows long and manually searching wasn't going to be an option, you just made my day go way faster xD.

Comment: @NateDeboer - If this solved it for you, please flag it as The Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post.  This shows the users on SO that it was solved by an Answer. (I see you edited the title - as I mentioned, the correct way to mark solved is simply to tick the check mark :)    )